# How to show/hide bottom navigation view on scroll listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, bottomnavigationview

**UPDATE:**

The bottom navigationview that I am implementing is only for a single fragment and not inside any activity so as to switch between fragments. The purpose of the bottomnavigation is to provide the sort functionality on scroll behaviour of the listview;similar to what happens in flipkart/paytm.

I have a listview inside a fragment and I want a bottomnavigationview which should behave as:

1.Initially, when the listview is being loaded, the bottomnavigationview should appear at the bottom of the fragment.

2. When the list is scrolled up, the navigationview should disappear.
3. When the list is scrolled down, it should disappear.

I have referred to the answers on stackoverflow and tried their code but none of them works for me.Can anyone brief me one this?

If there are better ways to achieve this, please let me know.
I am also doubtful whether the drawerlayout is necessary with this?

**Here is my fragment code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout-->
    <!--xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
    <!--xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"-->
    <!--xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--tools:context=".AvailableFood">-->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".AvailableFood">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <customfonts.MyEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/food_req"
            android:hint="Your requirement(kg) today?"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_avl_food"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!--</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>-->
```

**And here is how I apply the navigationview behavior:**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_available_food, container, false);

        mBottomNavigationView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomNavigationView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationBehavior());
}
```

**BottomNavigationBehavior.java:**

```
package com.example.student.doneate;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class BottomNavigationBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    public BottomNavigationBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public BottomNavigationBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, View dependency) {
        boolean dependsOn = dependency instanceof FrameLayout;
        return dependsOn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        if(dy < 0) {
            showBottomNavigationView(child);
        }
        else if(dy > 0) {
            hideBottomNavigationView(child);
        }
    }

    private void hideBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
    }

    private void showBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
BottomNavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
```

Comment: Add this line into bottomNavigationView xml:-> :>app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"  and layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationBehavior()); line from java code

Comment: I don't know why but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but, after nothing has helped, I found my own escape out of this.

Set the visibiity property of the bottomnavigation view using the onscrollListener on the ListView and it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In coordinate layout you have to use `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"`
In your `BottomNavigationView`

No need to do extra work in java code for hiding/showing `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: It says it Cannot resolve symbol '@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior'

Comment: What is your support library version? Update 28.0.0

Comment: Are you talking about :implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'? But my compileSdkVersion is 27 and it says This support library should not use a different version (28) than the compileSdkVersion (27) and my build fails when my update this

Comment: Update compileSdkVersion 28 and  targetSdkVersion 28 then it will show you to update com.android.support:design to 28.0.0

Comment: And don`t call BottomNavigationBehavior  in your java code (you can comment these code). Just use xml (one line)

Comment: You sure it won't cause any damage to my project?

Comment: Thats why i told you comment this line layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationBehavior()); and test it

Comment: I followed everything and this is what I get: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Comment: Did you update implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Comment: Yes..I followed everything you said

Comment: ok post here (only)BottomnavigationView  updated xml part here

Comment: i doubt that may be you are missing in somthing in gradle. or may not properly sync. Because the error say inflate exception. Bottomnavigation not inflating

Comment: And please tell me what is the code in #93 number line in your xml?

Comment: That is the line where the BottomNavigationView widget is placed. Shall I share my build.gradle file? Because now even the preview is not being rendered

Comment: In your preview may be you will get error and solution try it

Comment: Yes , it is shown now..But it does not show that required scrolling behaviour.

Comment: You can get good idea from here https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e

Comment: Could there be some problem with the listview being inflated from code behind from the server and the bottomnavigationview is always there?

Comment: You use frame layout i assume you using this to show fragment. And i don`t why you show listView above frameLayout? and its container linearlayout has no layout behaviour. and it is the main problem

Comment: Can you show what you say? Can you edit the code of my fragment?  I have updated my code by adding layout behaviour in the linear layout but still of no help

Comment: Whatever you have said is perfectly working inside activity, but how do I make it work for a single fragment?

Comment: It is nearly one month and you are keep improving this. So your bottom navigation is  located in fragment?

Comment: Yes. I think I have mentioned that earlier.